# Google App Engine / Web Toolkit: Access through proxy

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, proxy, gwt

I'm working on a Google Web Toolkit project, and have a service that requests data from a database. However, this service needs to pass through a proxy in order to fetch the required data. I've tried a variety of options, however most utilise InetSocketAddress, which is on the class blacklist for GAE. So far I've tried:

- System properties in appengine-web.xml
- -DhttpProxyHost etc. as java arguments
- System.setProperty(httpProxyPort) and its ilk.
- JVM proxy settings (!)

...to no avail. I have no way of accessing the DB without using these proxy settings. I'm at my wits' end here, so any help would be appreciated! How can I access content through a proxy in a GAE project?

Cheers,

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out Google App Engine isn't needs by GWT. Who knew? That said, simply disabling it didn't work - somewhere traces of it prevented the project from running. New project + copied classes solved it.

Joy.